# My code isnt writing to a list. The details are not displayed properly at the end

Tags: python, list, if-statement, input

This is how the code is supposed to work: User is prompted to choose a drink, then a cuisine, then a dish. After this, the program displays the order the user wanted.

The problem is that, when the customer enters in their details, the details are not displayed properly at the end.

What the code is supposed to do is displayed below the code.

```
print("Welcome to Hungary house.")
addDrink = input("Do you want a drink?\n").lower()
drinkChoice = "None"
dish = ""
order = []

if addDrink == "yes":
    print ("What drink would you prefer?")
    print ("1: Fanta")
    print ("2: Coke")
    print ("3: Pepsi")
    print ("4: Sprite")
    drinkChoice = input("please select a drink from the options above\n")

    if drinkChoice == "1" or drinkChoice == "fanta":
        drinkChoice = "Fanta"
        order.insert(0,drinkChoice)
    if drinkChoice == "2" or drinkChoice == "coke":
        drinkChoice = "Coke"
        order.insert(0,drinkChoice)
    if drinkChoice == "3" or drinkChoice == "pepsi":
        drinkChoice = "Pepsi"
        order.insert(0,drinkChoice)
    if drinkChoice == "4" or drinkChoice == "sprite":
        drinkChoice = "Sprite"
        order.insert(0,drinkChoice)

print ("you have chosen this drink: " + drinkChoice)

foodGroup = input("Do you want Indian or Chinese food?\n").lower()
if foodGroup == "indian" or foodGroup == "Indian":
    dish = input("Do you want Curry or onion bhaji?\n").lower()
    if dish == "Curry":
        order.insert(1,dish)
        dish = input("Do you want Rice or Naan?\n").lower()
        if dish == "Rice":
            order.insert(2,dish) 
        if dish == "Naan":
            order.insert(2,dish)

    if dish == "onion bhaji":
        order.insert(1,dish)
        dish = input("Do you want Chilli or Peppers?\n").lower()
        if dish == "Chilli":
            order.insert(2,dish)
        if dish == "Peppers":
            order.insert(2,dish)

if foodGroup == "chinese" or foodGroup == "Chinese":
    dish = input("Do you want Chicken Wings or Noodles?\n").lower()
    if dish == "Chicken Wings":
        order.insert(1,dish)
        dish = input("Do you want Chips or Red peppers?\n").lower()
        if dish == "Chips":
            order.insert(2,dish) 
        if dish == "Red peppers":
            order.insert(2,dish)

    if dish == "Noodles":
        order.insert(1,dish)
        dish = input("Do you want Meatballs or Chicken?\n").lower()
        if dish == "Meatballs":
            order.insert(2,dish)
        if dish == "Chicken":
            order.insert(2,dish)

print ("You have ordered the following",order,"You are order number 294")
```

The logic of this code is supposed to go as follows:

```
Welcome to Hungary house.
Do you want a drink?
If no, Move on to the next question
If yes, ask what drink the customer wants.
(Coke, Fanta, lemonade are the options)
If coke is chosen, set coke as drink
If Fanta is chosen, set Fanta as drink
If Lemonade is chosen, set Lemonade as drink
```

Do you want Indian or Chinese food?

```
If Indian food is entered ask the following questions
Do you want Curry or onion bhaji?
If curry is selected ask the following questions.
What toppings you want on top of your Curry?
Rice 
Or 
Naan
If user enters rice, add rice on to the curry.
If user enters Naan, add naan on to the curry.
If user enters onion ask the following questions.
What toppings do you want on top of your onion bhaji?
Chilli source
Or 
Naan 
If user enters Chilli source, add chilli source on to the onion bhaji.
If user enters Naan, add Naan on to the onion bhaji.
```

.

```
If Chinese food is entered ask the following questions.
Do you want Chicken wings or Noodles?
If Chicken wings is chosen ask,
Do you want with your Chicken wings?
Green Peppers
Or
Red Peppers
If Green pepper is chosen add that to the Green Peppers to the Chicken wings
If Red Peppers are chosen add that to the Chicken wings.
If the user enters Noodles ask the following questions.
Choose the toppings you want with Noodles.
Meatballs 
Or
Chicken 
If user enters Meatballs, add Meatballs to the Noodles.
If user enters Chicken, add Chicken to the Noodles.
```

After this, display the order the user wanted, tell the customer that their order will come within the next *10-50 minutes*. If they wish to cancel tell them to contact this number ‘077 3475 XXXXXX’.

Comment: every time you use "or", you could use "in": if drinkChoice == "2" or drinkChoice == "coke" can also be written: if drinkChoice in ["2", "coke"]

Comment: this test will NEVER work: dish = input("Do you want Curry or onion bhaji?\n").lower() ....if dish == "Curry"   "Curry" cannot have an uppercase C as you are converting the user input to lower case.

Comment: funny you had the idea to make yes and no .tolower, and you didn't do the same with fanta, despite you expect lowers while you display Fanta

Comment: @Luis Sieira So what should i do?

Comment: @Apero could you please answer the question and show me an example

Answer (score 1):

```
# Let's put the initialization stuff up front:
Order = [ 'No drink', 'No food' ]
Yesses = [ 'y', 'yes', 'yep', 'si', 'hai', 'sure', 'haan', 'why not?', 'ja', 'da' ]
DRINK = 0
FOOD = 1

print("Welcome to Hungary house!")

print("")
print("First, let me get your drink order, if any.")

answer = input("Would you like something to drink? ").lower()

if answer in Yesses:
    print("What drink would you prefer?")
    print ("1: Fanta")
    print ("2: Coke")
    print ("3: Pepsi")
    print ("4: Sprite")

    choice = input("Please enter a drink from the menu above\n").lower()

    if choice == "1" or choice == "fanta":
        Order[DRINK] = "Fanta"
    if choice == "2" or choice == "coke":
        Order[DRINK] = "Coke"
    if choice == "3" or choice == "pepsi":
        Order[DRINK] = "Pepsi"
    if choice == "4" or choice == "sprite":
        Order[DRINK] = "Sprite"

print ("You have chosen: " + Order[DRINK])

print("")
print("Now, let me get your food order, if any.")

answer = input("Do you want any food (Y/N)? ").lower()
if answer in Yesses:
    answer = input("Do you want Indian or Chinese food?\n").lower()

    if answer == "indian":
        answer = input("Do you want Curry or Onion Bhaji?\n").lower()

        if answer == "curry":
            Order[FOOD] = "Curry"

            answer = input("With your curry, do you want Rice or Naan?\n").lower()
            if answer == "rice":
                Order.append("- with rice")
            if answer == "naan":
                Order.append("- with naan")

        if answer == "onion bhaji" or answer == "bhaji":
            Order[FOOD] = "Onion Bhaji"

            answer = input("With your bhaji, do you want Chili or Peppers?\n").lower()
            if answer == "chili":
                Order.append("- with chili")
            if answer == "peppers":
                Order.append("- with peppers")
    if answer == "chinese":
        answer = input("Do you want Chicken Wings or Noodles?\n").lower()

        if answer == "chicken wings" or answer == "wings":
            Order[FOOD] = "Chicken Wings"

            answer = input("With your wings, do you want Chips or Red Peppers?\n").lower()
            if answer == "chips":
                Order.append("- with Chips")
            if answer == "red peppers" or answer == "peppers":
                Order.append("- with Red Peppers")

        if answer == "noodles":
            Order[FOOD] = "Noodles"

            answer = input("With your noodles, do you want Meatballs or Chicken?\n").lower()
            if answer == "meatballs":
                Order.append("- with meatballs")
            if answer == "chicken":
                Order.append("- with chicken")

try:
    if Order[2]:
        print("You have ordered the following. Your order number is 294")
        print("")
        print("    ", Order[DRINK])
        print("    ", Order[FOOD])
except:
    pass

try:
    if Order[2]:
        print("    ",Order[2])
except:
    print("")
    print("No food or drink?! Get out!")

try:
    if Order[2]:
        print("""
        Your order should arrive within 10-50 minutes. If you wish to cancel,
        please contact us at 077 3475 8675309. Thank you for your patronage!
        """)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Can you please validate this

Comment: So if i type something wrong it keeps looping until I give a valid answer? @R Kap

Comment: @Rdowg If you type something wrong, it assumes none of the above. However, I could make it so that it keeps on looping until you give a valid answer.

Comment: If you could make it so it keeps looping please @R.Kap

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `list.insert(1, dish)` do `list.append(dish)`. Since you are not inserting items before the end of the list `.append()` will work just fine for you. Example code:

```
if drinkChoice == "2" or drinkChoice == "coke":
    order.append("Coke")
```

Also, making a string with the contents `Coke` then adding that string to the list is pointless, you can add the string directly to the list as I show above.

Another example:

```
if dish == "onion bhaji":
    order.append(dish)
    dish = input("Do you want Chilli or Peppers?\n").lower()
    if dish == "chilli":
        order.append(dish)
    if dish == "peppers":
        order.append(dish)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Alfabravo could you show me another example please.

Comment: @Rdowg I just added another example.

Comment: In your second example, Chilli does not write to a list

Comment: @Rdowg Probably because you are checking to see if it matches `Chilli` but you have it turning the input into lowercase chars with `.lower()`

Comment: @Jasan Heddle so what should I do?

Comment: @Rdowg have it check for `"chilli"` not `"Chilli"`. Also, I would recommend learning some basic Python before asking questions here.

Comment: use lower everywhere, and match only to lowers

Comment: @Jasan Heddle How do I display it so when it displays what the customers ordered at the end as,For example "You have ordered the following ['Coke', 'onion bhaji', 'chilli']" But instead it says "You have ordered the following ['Coke', 'onion bhaji',WITH 'chilli']

Comment: Remove the "the following"

Comment: @Rdowg I am not here to write code for you, I am here to try and help you solve problems. Try something yourself.

Comment: If you need to, you can discuss in the SO chats. Otherwise, the comments are not intended to extend on different questions. Just a friendly reminder.